# Does the '@' character have any meaning in comments?

Tags: documentation, comments, preprocessor

I have a file copied from a coding example where the following comments were included:

/** @addtogroup CMSIS
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup stm32f30x_system
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup STM32F30x_System_Private_Includes
  * @{
  */

I am using the IAR EWARM dev environment coding in C for an STM32F303x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\addtogroup` or `@addtogroup` is a [doxygen command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdaddtogroup).

So you'd only want to keep those comments if you're using doxygen to produce API documentation from your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is such thing called "pseudo comments". They were introduced way before C. Source code is processed not only by the compiler. Other programs may also read it. These are formatters, static checkers for defects, company style checkers, interface extractors, etc. Often case they want to know more about the code. The most simple way to communicate this additional information to these tools is comments. These programs look for comments that have certain form, that is obviously specific for each tool. Doxygen above is a good example. There are tons of other tools that expect other specially formatted comments.

The bottom line:

- You need pseudo comments for the tool "Blah" only if you are using
  (or expecting to use) this tool. Otherwise, especially if you are not sure what they mean, it is better to delete them.
- You can safely assume that compiler with ignore contents of any comment. Well, except for very rare case when documentation for your compiler says opposite.